# Are questions about drupal's git/forking mechanism on topic?

Tags: discussion

I posted a [question about how to fork projects on drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297736/how-do-i-create-a-merge-request-for-a-project) which has a vote-to-close on it, and now I'm wondering whether it's on topic.

I actually checked the guidelines before posting it and convinced myself that based on this it's fine;

> If your question is about one of the following topics, you're in the
> right place!
>
> - **Drupal development/theming how-tos**
> - Site troubleshooting Site-building how-tos
> - Support questions for specific modules that aren't about bug workarounds
> - Drupal terminology or jargon

Whoever voted on it seems to disagree though. Thoughts?

Comment: The general "rule" is that only questions that require Drupal knowledge to answer them are on-topic for us. A question that could be answered even from users who have never used Drupal, or developed for Drupal, isn't on-topic for us. If there isn't any element that makes the answer different from the answer given for the same question asked for Joomla, WordPress, other CMS's, or plain PHP, the question is off-topic for us.

Comment: Questions about drupal.org have their own tag, and the git/fork/patch process is somewhat unique to Drupal and requires some special knowledge or understanding, especially if the official docs are not clear on that. So I think it's absolutely on-topic.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297736/how-do-i-create-a-merge-request-for-a-project is on-topic as it's asking how to achieve something on drupal.org, which is the official site for Drupal, a site that isn't used from users who don't use Drupal or develop for Drupal. A user who would know how to achieve the same on github.com, for example, could not answer about drupal.org.

Comment: Yes definitely on topic, great question for the site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only questions that require Drupal knowledge to answer them are on-topic for us. A question that could be answered even from users who have never used Drupal or developed Drupal code isn't on-topic for us.

In the specific case, a question asking how to achieve something on drupal.org is on-topic since drupal.org is the official site for Drupal, and it's used from users who create and manage Drupal sites or develop Drupal code.